# SQL: If exists, update else insert

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am very new to SQL and PHP but I want to add a user to a list if an entry does not already exist with their ip. If the entry does exist I just want to update their username.

I can perform both of these operations outside of the "if exists" statement without hiccups but it obviously creates a lot of duplicates. When I wrap it in the "if exists" statement the query stops doing anything.

I know there are a few questions regarding the subject but I have tried following most of the advice, if there is another way to do this I would be happy to consider it, thank you.

```
<?php
$username = strval($_GET['username']);
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ramendev_jctwood", "M1n1flam3", "ramendev_jctwood") or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($con, "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Userip='$userip')
                        UPDATE Users SET User='$username' WHERE Userip='$userip'
                    ELSE
                        INSERT INTO Users (User, Userip) VALUES ('$username', '$userip')
                            ");
?>
```

Comment: why not `insert ... on duplicate key update`? Any why are you not checking for sql errors? `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error())` would tell you EXACTLY what's wrong.

Comment: Try adding a semi-colon at the end of the UPDATE line, and at the end of the INSERT line.

Comment: Many SQL DBMSs have extensions to handle that.  I'm not sure which offers @Marc B's `on duplicate key update`, but SQLite has `insert or replace into`, and I'm sure there are other variations.

Comment: @john: it's mysql, which OP is obviously using since he's got `mysqli_query()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL standard UPSERT call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252213/sql-standard-upsert-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in mysql  you can use the REPLACE commmand.

```
REPLACE INTO users set User='$username' , Userip='$userip'
```

the field Userip mustbe unique index ou primary key

see more in 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Userip='$userip') > 0
    UPDATE Users SET User='$username' WHERE Userip='$userip'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Users (User, Userip) VALUES ('$username', '$userip')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Userip='$userip'";
$check = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($check)) {
   $existdata = mysql_fetch_array($check);
   $newquery = "UPDATE Users SET User='$username' WHERE Userip='{$existdata['Userip']}'";
} else {
   $newquery = "INSERT INTO Users (User, Userip) VALUES ('$username', '$userip')";       
}
$execute = mysql_query($new_query);
if($execute){
   echo "Success";
} else {
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what doc tells us for the case when you have primary key http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```