# "Insert if not exists" in both MySQL and HSQLDB

Tags: mysql, hsqldb

Is there a SQL statement (or atomic sequence of statements) supported by both MySQL and HSQLDB to insert values if they aren't already there?

I'm working on an app that uses MySQL as its production database and HSQLDB for unit tests; I'd like to have a single "initial data import when the tables are empty" script.

MySQL supports `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, but HSQLDB doesn't; conversely, HSQLDB supports `MERGE` but MySQL doesn't.

Comment: Look at accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252213/sql-standard-upsert-call), I think it is the only way to go, if you do not want to preprocess scripts with some other script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSQLDb from version 2.3.4 adds support for `insert ignore`.

http://hsqldb.org/

> Version 2.3.4 added the UUID type for columns, SYNONYM for tables and
>   functions, PERIOD predicates, and auto-updated TIMESTAMP columns on
>   row updates. Other new features included the ability to cancel
>   long-running statements from JDBC as well as from admin sessions, and
>   UTF-16 file support for text table sources, in addition to 8-bit text
>   files. **MySQL compatibility for REPLACE, INSERT IGNORE and ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements**.

And

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.pdf (page 260).

> HyperSQL supports and translates INSERT IGNORE, REPLACE and ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE variations of INSERT into predictable and
>   error-free operations. When INSERT IGNORE is used, if any of the
>   inserted rows would violate a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint, that
>   row is not inserted. With multi-row inserts, the rest of the rows are
>   then inserted only if there is no other violation such as long strings
>   or type mismatch, otherwise the appropriate error is returned. When
>   REPLACE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is used, the rows that need
>   replacing or updating are updated with the given values. This works
>   exactly like an UPDATE statement for those rows. Referential
>   constraints and other integrity checks are enforced and update
>   triggers are activated. The row count returned is simply the total
>   number of rows inserted and updated.

Comment: Could you provide examles ?

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this problem you can enable syntax support for MySQl by adding the following to your script

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE
```